# gridfilters plugin + stateful grid

Tags: extjs

I'm using on my grid:

```
plugins: {
   gridfilters: true
},
```

Using ExtJS 7, Classic

I'm able to save the state of columns (position, width, etc.) but I can't find a way to save the applied filters on each column.

I guess there's no documentation for that.

Is it possible? How should I proceed?

Thanks.

Comment: Try to get filters from the store of the grid, not the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only using `gridfilters` it is easy:

```
    plugins: {
        gridfilters: true
    },

    stateId: 'myGridIdLikePersonell',
    stateful: true,
```

In case this does not work for you, please add a fiddle.

---

If you are using gridfilterbar it does not come out of the box.
Most stateful items, which are not as easy as 'width' (which has a getter and setter) are a bit more work.

0. [optional] create a plugin which mixes in `Ext.state.Stateful`
1. add a stateId and `stateful:['gridFilter']`
2. add a config `gridFilter`
3. on init add a listener to the grid store `filterchange`
4. onFilterChange grab the property and value from each filter to define the filter. Update your stateful gridFilter (setGridFilter from config-gridFilter)
5. override the `loadState` method to allow you to write the filter back to the store
6. add a funtion being called from loadState and add `store.filter(filter)`

Voila - thats it